# Nginx 404 not found with no suffix /

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, containers

I'm trying to run Nginx on my local.
with the next default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;


    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location /buy/ {
    alias /var/www/buy/;
   }

    location /sell/ {
    alias /var/www/sell/;
}
}
```

When I run `Nginx` and try to hit `localhost:80/buy/` I get the expected page.
but when I hit `localhost:80/buy` (**without the suffix /**) I got 404 not found.

any idea?

Comment: As `/buy` does not match any `location`, Nginx uses the value of `root` defined in your `server` block.

Comment: even so, if i define location /buy still same issue.

Comment: Define `location /buy` how? And did you clear the browser's cache and rebuild Nginx between changes?

Comment: i defined it exactly how i defined the location /buy/.
and it's build from docker container so every time I create a new image.

Comment: You are using `alias` in `location /buy/`, and it would need to be changed for `location /buy`. Try: `location /buy { root /var/www; }`